# str_replace characters PHP

Tags: php, arrays, str-replace

I have this array :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Windows#XP
            [1] => 3620
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Windows#Vista
            [1] => 1901
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Windows#7
            [1] => 88175
        )
```

and so on...I want to replace `#` with an space here's my code and it doesnt seem to work:

```
$tab_os = str_replace('#',' ',$tab_os);
```

Any solution for that?

Thanks!

Comment: is `$tab_os` the name of the array?

Comment: What does the variable $tab_os contain?

Comment: yeah! when I print_array($tab_os) it displays me the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
foreach ($tab_os as $key => $value){
   $tab_os[$key]  = str_replace('#',' ',$value);
}
```

but really, str_replace accepts and returns arrays so this shouldn't be the problem. see [docs](http://php.net/str_replace)

---

I have tried and tested this code, try it here: http://codepad.org/Ok1fZ16O

```
$tab_os = array( array( "Windows#XP", 1 ), array( "Windows#7", 1 ) );

foreach ($tab_os as $key => $value) {
   $tab_os[$key]  = str_replace('#', ' ', $value);
}

var_dump($tab_os);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$tab_os = array(
    array('Windows#XP', 3620),
    array('Windows#Vista', 1901),
    array('Windows#7', 88175),
);

foreach ($tab_os as $os_k => $os_v){
   $tab_os[$os_k] = str_replace('#', ' ', $os_v);
}
print_r($tab_os);
```

You need to loop through it

Answer (score 1):

Because loops are too mainstream *(and also because it's a bit faster)*, you can use [array_map()](https://www.php.net/array_map) :

```
function replaceValue($value) {
    return str_replace('#', ' ', $value[0]);
}

array_map('replaceValue', $tab_os);
```

Comment: array_map is a hidden loop though.

Comment: Yes, but the difference is that it uses callbacks that don't wait the end of the operations within the loop to go to the next element.